# Dependable fields in custom widget

Tags: magento2, custom, widgets, dependent-fields

I have created a custom widget having Title and dropdown field and image chooser.
I wish to add dependable fields.the image uploading field is visible according with drop down menu.
**widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Widget/etc/widget.xsd">
<widget id="wk_customwidget" class="Dyode\PromotionWidget\Block\CustomWidget">
    <label translate="true">Promotion block Widget</label>
    <description>Widget for banner blocks</description>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="blocktitle" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" required="true" sort_order="1">
        <label translate="true">Block Title</label>
        <description>Enter block title</description>
    </parameter>
        <parameter name="select_type" xsi:type="select" required="true" source_model="Dyode\PromotionWidget\Model\Config\Source\Select" visible="true" sort_order="8" >
            <label translate="true">Select option</label>
            <description>Select type option</description>
          </parameter>
          <parameter name="desktop_image" xsi:type="block" required="true" visible="true" sort_order="10">
           <label translate="true">DeskTop Image </label>
           <description>Upload Image for desktop view</description>
           <block class="Dyode\PromotionWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\ImageChooser">
               <data>
                   <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Choose Image...</item>
                   </item>
               </data>
           </block>
       </parameter>
       <parameter name="mobile_image" xsi:type="block" required="true" visible="true" sort_order="10">
        <label translate="true">Mobile Image</label>
        <description>Upload Image for Mobile view</description>
        <block class="Dyode\PromotionWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\ImageChooser">
            <data>
                <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Choose Image...</item>
                </item>
            </data>
        </block>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="imageurl" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" required="true" sort_order="11">
      <label translate="true">URL</label>
      <description>Enter reference url</description>
  </parameter>
    </parameters>
</widget>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Magento widget has a built in element for dependable fields. Just like label and description, you can use 'depends' as an element inside parameter.

```
<parameter name="child_parameter" sort_order="10" visible="true" xsi:type="text" required="false">
    <label translate="true">Label</label>
    <description translate="true">Description</description>
    <depends>
        <parameter name="{{parent_parameter_name}}" value="{{parent_parameter_selected_value}}"/>
    </depends>
</parameter>
```